# Calculated column based on value of other column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, calculated-column

I have two fields in a SharePoint list - 1. Archive Status (Choice field which are Active, Archived and Cancelled) and 2. Archived Date (Date Field).
Is it possible to automatically calculate the Archive Date column when Archive Status is set to Archived or Cancelled?

Comment: you need to conctenate Archive status and data column in the calculated field?

Comment: How is your archived Date calculated? Could you provide the formula on different status? For many scenarios, we may need to use workflow to do this job

Answer (score 0):

Without out knowing more, such as what value you want to calculate for the date, maybe something like this:

```
=IF([Archive Status]="Active",
    [Created]+90,
    IF([Archive Status]="Archived",
       [Created]+30,
       [Created]
      )
   )
```

If not Active or Archived, then use the Created date to archive immediately.